# Accessing application.properties value in logback-access.xml

Tags: properties, logback

application.properties

```
application_name : "xyz"
```

Logback-access.xml
`${application_name}`

This is giving application name as undefined.

Can anyone provide the solution for it?

I tried adding
`<property resource ="application.properties>`